# Crear extensión personalizada Slim+Twig

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

Tengo creado un gestor de plantillas con `Slim+Twig` y funciona bien.
El problema es al intentar añadir una Extensión, me da error al llamar a la extensión desde el archivo `.twig`, y no se exactamente cual puede ser el error:

**index.php**

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware;

use Helpers\PaginatorTwigExtension;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create App
$app = AppFactory::create();

// Create Twig
$twig = Twig::create('path/to/templates', ['cache' => false]);

// Add Twig-View Middleware
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::create($app, $twig));

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) use () {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);

    return $view->render($response, 'index.twig', []);
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

**PaginatorTwigExtension.php**

```
<?php
namespace Helpers;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

/**
 * Twig extension to help generate simple paginations.
 */
class PaginatorTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    public function getName() {
        return 'paginator';
    }

    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('paginator', [$this, 'generatePaginationData']),
        ];
    }

    public function generatePaginationData(int $curr_page, int $last_page, int $num_items = 7, string $separator = '...') {
        return array(
            'curr_page' => $curr_page, 
            'last_page' => $last_page, 
            'num_items' => $num_items, 
            'separator' => $separator, 
            'pagination' => $pagination
        );
    }
}
```

Al llamar a la extensión desde el archivo `index.twig`, lo hago así:

```
{% set paginator = paginator(10, 25 , 11, '...') %}
```

Pero me da este error:

> Unknown "paginator" function.

Mi pregunta es, ¿me falta algo para incluir esta extensión personalizada? ¿o hay que llamarlo de otra forma?